# Adding the all the data from the database in the set_userdata function in Code Igniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to add the data of the user from the database in the set_userdata() function in Code Igniter and my code is not working. When i display the userdata() all of the fields from the database didnt displayed. Can you check whats wrong? NEWBIE IN CODE IGNITER HERE :(

```
 if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $userinfo=$this->model_users->get_user_info();
            $data = array(
                'empID' => $userinfo->empID,
                'email' => $userinfo->email,
                'emp_name' => $userinfo->emp_name,
                'address' => $userinfo->address,
                'position' => $userinfo->position,
                'usertype' => $userinfo->usertype,
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('main/home');
        } else{
            $this->login();
        }
```

and here is the code from the model

```
 public function can_log_in(){
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));

    $query = $this->db->get('employee');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function get_user_info(){
     $query = $this->db->get_where('employee',array('email'=> $this->input->post('email'),'password'=> md5($this->input->post('password'))));
       foreach ($query->result() as $userinfo)
            {
               echo $userinfo->empID;
               echo $userinfo->email;
               echo $userinfo->emp_name;
               echo $userinfo->address;
               echo $userinfo->position;
               echo $userinfo->usertype;
            }
        return $userinfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `$query->result` from your model if yu get any rows from your query. afterforech loop variable `$userinfo` is empty so its return nothig

**Model**

```
function get_user_info(){
     $query = $this->db->get_where('employee',array('email'=> $this->input->post('email'),'password'=> md5($this->input->post('password'))));
     $num = $query->num_rows();
     if($num>0){
       return $query->result();
     }else{
          return FALSE;
     }
```

Here you use foreach loop to extract your value

**Controller**

```
$user=$this->model_users->get_user_info();
if(!empty($user)){
      foreach($user as $userinfo){
            $data = array(
                'empID' => $userinfo->empID,
                'email' => $userinfo->email,
                'emp_name' => $userinfo->emp_name,
                'address' => $userinfo->address,
                'position' => $userinfo->position,
                'usertype' => $userinfo->usertype,
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );
}
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
```

**Updated**

**MODEL**

```
function get_user_info() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('employee');
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query=$this->db->get();
     $num = $query->num_rows();
     if($num>0){
       return $query->row();
     }else{
          return FALSE;
     }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$user=$this->model_users->get_user_info();
    if(!empty($user)){
                $data = array(
                    'empID' => $userinfo->empID,
                    'email' => $userinfo->email,
                    'emp_name' => $userinfo->emp_name,
                    'address' => $userinfo->address,
                    'position' => $userinfo->position,
                    'usertype' => $userinfo->usertype,
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
```

Comment: the session was not set so meaning the user was returned empy. what couldve been the problem?

Comment: after implementing my code are you able to set `set_userdata`??

Comment: no the set_userdata was not set. cause i cant get into my homepage :( @Saty

Comment: okk `print_r($user);` in your controller and check the value of it

Comment: im stuck in a blank page and it does not display anything. @Saty

Comment: i just copied your code. and it didnt seem to work in the `if(!empty($user)){}` part cause i just tested it and i think $user was empty thats why it didnt execute. @Saty

Comment: check what is the value of `$this->input->post('email')` and password

Comment: i checked for them and they have values. but when i check with print_r($query->result()); it didnt have any values. the array was empty.. i checked them in the model by the way. @Saty

Comment: first you check the value of email and password is set or not!!what is the value of `$this->input->post('email')`

Comment: hash or md5 ??please comform it.

Comment: already told you the values are set.. the value for email is albert@gmail.com while for the password is the password with md5 @Saty

Comment: still not working.. i tried print_r($query->result); in the model and the array is empty

Comment: So try to echo your query and run it in your phpmyadmin so that you can check whether your query is wrong or not.

Comment: well thank you so much for the help. it was fixed when i just used the $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM employee"); syntax. thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new array instead of storing in $data.

```
 $sess_array = array();
            $sess_array = array(
                'id'          => $user_info->admin_id,
                'username'    => $user_info->username,
                'password'    => $user_info->password,
                'last_name'   => $user_info->last_name,
                'first_name'  => $user_info->first_name,
                'profile_img' => $user_info->img,
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

and then you can call so-

```
$sess_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
echo $sess_data['profile_img']; //This holds the result similarly other values.
```

Comment: in your model- `$this->db->get('employee')->row();` you should get similarly in userinfo section also.

Comment: have you checked the array userinfo you are passing?are getting the values printed?

Comment: I didn't checked. Its a little bit complicated. Im just a beginner in CI :(